# C++ and destructors (nested classes and general questions)

Tags: c++, struct, destructor

I am working on an implementation of a binary tree in C++.  I am fairly new to the language, and while I understand what structs and destructors are, I am not sure about what happens with nested classes/structs.

In my implementation, I have a nested struct for my binary node.  Does this struct need its own destructor, or will all of the nodes be deleted when the destructor for the binary tree itself get called.  Does the answer change if I change the struct to a class?

Also, I was told that if you ever call "new" in a class, you need to call "delete" in the destructor.  If I initialize an array in my initialization list for a class (i.e. class: array({0})), do I need to delete [] array in my destructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting one class (or struct) within another has no effect on the lifetime of the objects.  All it does is provide a scope for the class's name, and access to private members in the enclosing class.  So your tree nodes won't be automatically destroyed just by virtue of being nested in the tree class.

If you want a tree's nodes to be destroyed when the tree itself is destroyed, you need to ensure that the tree's destructor does that.  If you're allocating the nodes manually with `new`, use `delete` (or `delete[]`) in the destructor.  Alternatively, you can use something like `std::auto_ptr` (or `std::unique_ptr` in C++11), which will do the cleanup in its own destructor so you don't have to write the `delete` calls yourself.

Changing a struct to a class has no effect on its behavior at runtime.  The only difference between a struct and a class in C++ is that a struct's body implicitly begins with `public:` and a class's body implicitly begins with `private:`.

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary for C++ that we have to define destructors in our class/struct.
there is no any changes in destructor if you are going to change struct to class.
but it is good for programming language that if we call memory with new, we have to delete it ourself.
if you are going to define nested class than it is good to make destructor in that class also.

there is no need to use for delete[] for array.